# Update CSS Variable with Javascript On page load without causing a flicker or glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using one HTML file as the template for many pages and want to show different coloured buttons and links on some pages. I am trying to use CSS VARIABLES so that I can update them with javascript. But it all happens once the JS is loaded which causes a glitch.

Can anyone suggest a better solution or any alternative approach?

Project uses Jquery, Bootstrap and a Laravel backend.

Comment: Use loading screen until your JS is ready.

Comment: Output dynamic CSS from Laravel.

Comment: you could load the JS before the HTML is loaded

Comment: You could try to alter the css by generating it in the backend. Then the valid css gets loaded once you get the css file. PS: How are you altering the css variables with JS?